# How to make better crop plots in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Crop plots look something like this:

[image]

The above shows a calendar year and bars that cover various seasons for each crop.

I have been trying to make a "crop plot" for sports, by recreating the following plot:

[image]

Here is my attempt:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
cal <- tribble(
  ~sport,   ~reg,          ~year_end,    ~year_begin, ~reg_end,       ~pst_end, 
  "nfl",    "2017-09-07",  "2017-12-31", "2017-01-01" ,"2017-01-01",   "2017-02-05",
  "nba",    "2017-10-18",  "2017-12-31", "2017-01-01" ,"2017-04-13",   "2017-06-19",
  "mlb",    "2017-04-02",  "2017-10-04", "2017-10-04" ,"2017-10-04",   "2017-11-02",
  # don't want to designate a pst season for ncaa_fb. 
  "ncaa_fb","2017-08-26",  "2017-12-31", "2017-01-01" ,"2017-01-10",   "2017-01-10",
)

ggplot(cal, aes(x=sport)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin=reg, ymax=year_end), color="#324D5C", size=5) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin=year_begin, ymax=reg_end), color="#324D5C", size=5) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin=reg_end, ymax=pst_end), color="#ED3752", size=5) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Created on 2018-08-21 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

I have two questions/problems:

1. Is there are better way to handle the season "wraping" around the year? currently I have to specify a year end date and a year beginning date to give the appearance of the season wrapping.
2. How can I get two labels for an axis? They have an axis for date, but two labels (month and quarter). It looks like I can only specify one label.
3. Is there a better way to go about making these kind of plots? Right now this processes feel very manual. I wonder if someone else has had success with another method.

#### Extra:

Similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806845/plotting-crop-calendars).

### Edit

This original data is large, so I will not `dput` is here, but this is the first few rows. Hopefully this gives some idea as to the form of the data.

```r
        date   sport event
1 2017-12-31 nfl_reg     1
2 2017-12-30 nfl_reg     0
3 2017-12-29 nfl_reg     0
4 2017-12-28 nfl_reg     0
5 2017-12-27 nfl_reg     0
6 2017-12-26 nfl_reg     0
```

Comment: Labels may be iffy. Another option would be to color background of the plot according to quarter.

Comment: For two rows of axis labels it looks annoying but possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18167422/4421870

Comment: How are the dates originally given, before you manually split to wrap them around the year?

Comment: I had a list of all the days in a year then an indicator for if a game happened on that date or not.

Comment: a calendar year or season year? i'm trying to figure out a better way to do the wrapping but you've given us already-wrapped dates, so i'm guessing a little.

Comment: @CalumYou I have a calendar year column and an indicator column.

Comment: Dude. Make it easy for everyone and post a slice of your data that illustrates the variation. Otherwise we're just poking holes in the darkness. Right you have 5 rows in total, one row with a game. What's the expected output from that?