# ggplot2 - How to plot length of time using geom_bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, timeline

I am trying to show different growing season lengths by displaying crop planting and harvest dates at multiple regions.

My final goal is a graph that looks like this:

[image]

which was taken from an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806845/plotting-crop-calendars/). Note that the dates are in julian days (day of year).

My first attempt to reproduce a similar plot is:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

mydat <- "Region\tCrop\tPlanting.Begin\tPlanting.End\tHarvest.Begin\tHarvest.End\nCenter-West\tSoybean\t245\t275\t1\t92\nCenter-West\tCorn\t245\t336\t32\t153\nSouth\tSoybean\t245\t1\t1\t122\nSouth\tCorn\t183\t336\t1\t153\nSoutheast\tSoybean\t275\t336\t1\t122\nSoutheast\tCorn\t214\t336\t32\t122"

# read data as data table
mydat <- setDT(read.table(textConnection(mydat), sep = "\t", header=T))

# melt data table
m <- melt(mydat, id.vars=c("Region","Crop"), variable.name="Period", value.name="value")

# plot stacked bars
ggplot(m, aes(x=Crop, y=value, fill=Period, colour=Period)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(~Region, nrow=3) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw(base_size=18) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("Planting.Begin" = "black", "Planting.End" = "black",
                                 "Harvest.Begin" = "black", "Harvest.End" = "black"), guide = "none")
```

[image]

However, there's a few issues with this plot:

1. Because the bars are stacked, the values on the x-axis are aggregated and end up too high - out of the 1-365  scale that represents day of year.
2. I need to combine `Planting.Begin` and `Planting.End` in the same color, and do the same to `Harvest.Begin` and `Harvest.End`.
3. Also, a "void" (or a completely uncolored bar) needs to be created between `Planting.Begin` and `Harvest.End`.

Perhaps the graph *could* be achieved with `geom_rect` or `geom_segment`, but I really want to stick to `geom_bar` since it's more customizable (for example, it accepts `scale_colour_manual` in order to add black borders to the bars).

Any hints on how to create such graph?

Comment: Hi OP - can you share the dataset, `m` please?  If it is not too large (<50 rows), you can share directly in your question (preferred) via typing `dput(m)` into your console and pasting the output of that function (should start with `structure(...`) into your question, formatted as code.  If `m` is too large, then I would recommend sending maybe one of the `Region`s in your dataset.

Comment: @chemdork123 thanks for your comment, but... the data is all in the question. `m` is just a 'melted' version of `mydat`. Are you unable to run the code?

Comment: Oh I see... you have `"\"` delimited data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is something you can do with a `geom_bar` or `geom_col`. A more general approach would be to use `geom_rect` to draw rectangles. To do this, we need to reshape the data a bit

```
plotdata <- mydat %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Crop = factor(Crop)) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(Planting.Begin:Harvest.End, names_to="period") %>% 
  tidyr::separate(period, c("Type","Event")) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from=Event, values_from=value)


#    Region      Crop    Type     Begin   End
#    <chr>       <fct>   <chr>    <int> <int>
#  1 Center-West Soybean Planting   245   275
#  2 Center-West Soybean Harvest      1    92
#  3 Center-West Corn    Planting   245   336
#  4 Center-West Corn    Harvest     32   153
#  5 South       Soybean Planting   245     1
#  ...
```

We've used `tidyr` to reshape the data so we have one row per rectangle that we want to draw and we've also make Crop a factor. We can then plot it like this

```
ggplot(plotdata) + 
  aes(ymin=as.numeric(Crop)-.45, ymax=as.numeric(Crop)+.45, xmin=Begin, xmax=End, fill=Type) + 
  geom_rect(color="black") + 
  facet_wrap(~Region, nrow=3) + 
  theme_bw(base_size=18) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq_along(levels(plotdata$Crop)), labels=levels(plotdata$Crop))
```

[image]

The part that's a bit messy here that we are using a discrete scale for `y` but `geom_rect` prefers numeric values, so since the values are factors now, we use the numeric values for the factors to create ymin and ymax positions. Then we need to replace the y axis with the names of the levels of the factor.

If you also wanted to get the month names on the `x` axis you could do something like

```
dateticks <- seq.Date(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-12-01"),by="month")
# then add this to you plot
  ... + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=lubridate::yday(dateticks),
                       labels=lubridate::month(dateticks, label=TRUE, abbr=TRUE))
```